# How to validate matDatepicker input in Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to validate date. It does validate in most cases, but when I enter
type number like 15042019, it does not show any error.

The problem is that custom validator I only gets `null` value or Date instance, so I don't have a chance to do some reqex matching:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input formControlName="ratingDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" 
       placeholder="Rating Date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>


this.formBuilder.group({
  ratingDate: ['', CustomValidators.date],
});
```

How do I validate date inputs, in Reactive Forms, when using mat-datepicker?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53284824/date-validation-using-angular-material-date-picker)

Comment: @Liero refrer this example of date validation : https://stackblitz.com/angular/moydnyrovrjq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-add.component.ts

Comment: @Liero this is not working im getting an error in my html page Property 'date' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['date']